# Find path of Mage::helper on FTP-Server?

Tags: template

I can see the following function in my template's minicart.phtml:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper("ves_tempcp/framework")->getMinicartBlock(); ?>
```

But on the FTP I can not find the folders **ves_tempcp/framework**. Where do I have to look for the path Mage::helper is looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are possibly looking for `app/code/community/Ves/Tempcp/Helper/Framework.php`
Next time you can also use [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-class.php) to see the object class name and then infer the location. For example

```
echo get_class(Mage::helper("ves_tempcp/framework"))
```

should return something like `Ves_Tempcp_Helper_Framework` telling you that the file should be in `app/code/[local][community]/Ves/Tempcp/Helper/Framework.php` if the correct naming conventions were used.

Answer (score 6):

What you're seeing is Magento's class alias system. What you're asking for is how to translate a class alias into a class name, and subsequently how a class name translates to a file path.

*TL;DR: The class you're looking for might be in app/code/local/Ves/Tempcp/Helper/Framework.php*

Continue reading for more background about this.

---

### Class Aliases

Magento uses a concept called a "class alias" that every module in `app/code/*` should define. See some examples below:

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
...
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <class>Mage_Catalog_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>catalog_resource</resourceModel>
        </catalog>
...
```

See the node `<catalog>` and its child `<class>` - "catalog" is the alias that Magento will use to resolve to the class prefix "Mage_Catalog_Model." This is defined in the context of models, and you will see a similar definition for blocks and helpers.

So when you want to call a helper with `Mage::helper('module/helper')` Magento will consult the configuration XML to lookup that alias. If found, it will replace it with the class name prefix, followed by a transformed version of everything after the `/` in the alias.

Your above call for a helper in the template translates something like this:

```
ves_tempcp/framework ==> Namespace_Module_Helper_Framework
```

Where `Namespace_Module` will be derived from what this module's `config.xml` declares as its alias.

### Class - File Path Relationship

It can roughly be said that a class name approximates the file path if you replace underscores with directory separators, ie:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Category ==> [app/code/core/]Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php
```

The path part in brackets is defined as part of Magento autoloading system.

There are some good resources by Alan Storm that touches on how the alias system works, and how Magento uses it to locate files:

> http://alanstorm.com/magento_config
>   http://alanstorm.com/magento_class_abstration_autoload

Comment: Rick - thanks for the great answer and background information. I can only mark one answer as the right one and I did with the one which I saw first...

Comment: No problem @Torben. It's a game of speed around here, and that answer *is* correct :)

Answer (score 1):

it will be located in

```
app/code/local
```

or

```
app/code/community
```